# Why does publish fail to publish System.Net.Http.dll?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, webclient

I have a WPF application written in C# that is failing to publish the System.Net.Http.dll and System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll.

When the user launches the application they receive the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

To replicate this issue:

1. Open VS2012
2. File -> New -> Project -> Visual C# -> WPF Application
3. Right-click references -> Manage NuGet Packages...
4. Add the *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries* by searching for **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client**
5. Right-click the project -> Properties
6. Click Publish tab
7. Uncheck *Automatically increment revision with each publish*
8. Click **Publish Now** button
9. Note that in the `publish\Application Files\WpfApplication1_1_0_0_0` folder you will see *System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.deploy* but you won't see the other two files, *System.Net.Http.dll.deploy* or *System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll.deploy*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Work-around**

---

For now, I've included the binaries at the project root.  This smells, but will have to do until a better solution comes around.

Steps to work-around:

1. Right-click the project -> Add... -> Existing Item
2. Browse to `SolutionRoot\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40` and select both *System.Net.Http.dll* and *System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll*
3. This adds both files as 'Content' to the application - you will get warnings ([MSBuild Error MSB3178](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228157%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) but it doesn't appear you can do anything about it
4. Note that now when you publish, both files will be in the `publish\Application Files\WpfApplication1_1_0_0_0` folder

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a better way?

Comment: 5 years later... Same issue... Is it such a joke?

Comment: Yeah, it seems the issue still exists. Just ran into the same issue. Please correct me if I'm wrong, would be much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a similar, but more descriptive answer. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917647/7311104