# How to Install a COM Object that has a Dependency chain

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, packaging

I need to install a C# COM object, however, my C# package has a dependency chain.

When trying to register the DLL I get this error message:

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I assume there's an elegant way to do this, rather than manually hunting down each DLL and making sure it's in the same directory as the DLL I'm registering, but I haven't been able to hunt down the solution.

I'm guessing there's either a way to package up all my dependent DLLs, or there's something wrong with my path where at least core .Net DLLs should be available in the path somewhere?

**Research**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092553/turn-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-into-a-com-interop-component) explains how to install a COM, but doesn't cover how to handle dependencies.

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736) does a similar job of explaining COM installation without mentioning dependencies.

Comment: The error message says that you are missing .NET System.Net.Http dependency, it is not related to COM. Until .NET 4.5, this assembly is not deployed as a part of the framework. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827611/deploying-system-net-http-dll-with-clickonce

Comment: Thanks, I think you've found the problem. It's a Server 2003 box I'm trying to install this on, so it only has .NET 4.0. There is apparently a workaround though, so not all is lost.