# Unable to Deploy System.Net.Http with ClickOnce installer

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

We are developing a .NET windows application and decided to use ClickOnce instead of just copy/paste files from release folder. 
After deployed and installed on user machine, we started to have the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

We saw that this file was not being deployed together with the application and found this Question [Deploying System.Net.Http.dll with ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827611/deploying-system-net-http-dll-with-clickonce) but says microsoft would solve the problem. We are using VS2017 and seems like the same result.

Could not  find what to do to fix this without a workaround. Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the reference that points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.X.X\System.Net.Http.dll` and simply add the **System.Net.Http NuGet package**.

This will be deployed without problem.

Comment: Same result. Won't generate System.Net.Http.dll.Deploy.

Comment: I have just created new solutions with latest VS 2017 and 2019. Framework 4.7.1 and System.Net.Http from NuGet. It works. If I set the project framework to 4.7.2, then the reference path changes back to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\..." and ClickOnce ignores the file. If I switch back to 4.7.1, the reference changes back to the NuGet package. I don't know why this is happening, but that's what I have noticed. Maybe it can help you...

Comment: I'm voting for this because worked locally, but still the same problem on azure devops.